# getting fileNotFoundException when running code on docker container using sbt native-packager

Tags: docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

i am creating a docker image of my akka http project using [sbt native-packager](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html)
here is my build.sbt file

```
name := "myproject-auth"

version := "0.0.1"

enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)

enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)

dockerExposedPorts := Seq(8083)
```

then i create my app image as

> `sbt docker:publishLocal`

it created my project image and runs fine the problem is
in my code i am reading a json file which reads from `src/main/resources/json1.json`

```
val jsonString = os.read(os.pwd / "src" / "main" / "resources" / "json1.json")
```

when i run this code in a docker container it says

```
docker-project-auth-container | java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/docker/src/main/resources/json1.json
```

the problem is how can i make my code to work in this scenario
as  i need to keep using sbt native packager it creates my project jar and the working dir is `/opt/docker` in docker container where the my project's shell script resides created by docker

here is the docker file created by sbt native-packager

```
FROM openjdk:8 as stage0
LABEL snp-multi-stage="intermediate"
LABEL snp-multi-stage-id="cc5bb9ac-866b-4baa-98e1-c4541030c6ae"
WORKDIR /opt/docker
COPY opt /opt
USER root
RUN ["chmod", "-R", "u=rX,g=rX", "/opt/docker"]
RUN ["chmod", "u+x,g+x", "/opt/docker/bin/myproject-auth"]

FROM openjdk:8
USER root
RUN id -u demiourgos728 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || (( getent group 0 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || ( type groupadd 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && groupadd -g 0 root || addgroup -g 0 -S root )) && ( type useradd 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && useradd --system --create-home --uid 1001 --gid 0 demiourgos728 || adduser -S -u 1001 -G root demiourgos728 ))
WORKDIR /opt/docker
COPY --from=stage0 --chown=demiourgos728:root /opt/docker /opt/docker
EXPOSE 8083
USER 1001:0
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/docker/bin/myproject-auth"]
CMD []
```

json1.json exists in a jar created by native-packager but it exists in root not in src/main/resources

opt/docker/ contains two folder `bin` and `lib`
`bin` contains `myproject-auth.sh` and `myproject-auth.bat` and `lib` contains myproject-auth.jar with other library dependencies
how can i make my code work inside a docker container